# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'monitoring'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow-hub

Recently installed `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_hub` in a `miniconda` environment and have an issue when trying to run a script. Receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow_hub as hub
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py", line 62, in <module>
    class LatestModuleExporter(tf_estimator.Exporter):
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import tpu
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/tpu/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_estimator import TPUEstimator
  File "/miniconda3/envs/CFS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 108, in <module>
    _tpu_estimator_gauge = tf.compat.v2.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'monitoring'
```

Package info is here:

```
$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/chris/miniconda3/envs/CFS:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
...
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
...
numpy                     1.22.3           py39hc58783e_2    conda-forge
...
pip                       22.2.2           py39h06a4308_0  
...
python                    3.9.5                h12debd9_4    anaconda
...
setuptools                65.5.0           py39h06a4308_0  
...
tensorboard               2.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.0            py39hd97740a_2    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.4.1           mkl_py39h4683426_0  
tensorflow-base           2.4.1           mkl_py39h43e0292_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0            py39he80948d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-hub            0.13.0             pyh56297ac_0    conda-forge
...
```

I don't have a tpu, but from the error, it looks like `tensorflow` is trying to use one?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try updating TensorFlow to a newer version, such as [2.12.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.12.0)? Version 2.4.1 is quite old now.

As for `tensorflow_hub`, you already have the freshest release.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that the package requires that specific version.